# Why can't my project use the NUnit reference?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

This is similar to a previous thread I made, but the problem is, I coded something at work, I took the solution home (by copying and pasting it to my usb pen). I pasted it to my desktop at home and when I build one of the projects in the sln (which is depdendent on NUnit), I get a bunch of errors like this:

The type or namespace name 'Framework' does not exist in the namespace 'NUnit' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Basically, any object referenced which is in NUnit is not recognised, as if (obviously) the assembly is missing, but it is not, it is in the project references/bin folder, and there is no yellow exclamation mark. This is a .NET 3.5 solution and I am not using client profile, which can cause this confusion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to open your .csproj or .vbproj file with notepad and find something like:

```
<Reference Include="nunit.framework, Version=2.5.5.10112, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.5.5\bin\net-2.0\framework\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Make sure you have the same version of the DLL and the file path is correct.

Comment: I fixed this by just removing/adding references again but that's a bit of a hack. I am likely going to have this problem again and when I do, I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check the hint path for nunit in your .csproj file. It might be hard coded to a different path, make it relative (if the DLL is in your solution), or just grab the right path.

I hope that's your solution!

Comment: if you look at the answer from Optillect Team, you can see the part that says <HintPath>...</HintPath>, that's the Hint path!, it's where the project looks to grab that DLL, it was probably either pointing to the incorrect folder before (maybe Program Files(x86)?) or something to that effect.